# How do I create multiple One-to-Many relationships to the same table in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

So first off, I want to clarify that I am trying to make One-To-Many relationships, not Many-to-One.  I already understand how ForeignKeys work.

For the sake of the discussion, I've simplified my models; they're much more field-rich than this in the real implementation.

I have a model, called a `ColumnDefinition`:

```
class ColumnDefinition(Model):
    column_name = CharField(max_length=32)
    column_type = PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    column_size = PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I think have a registry.  Each registry has a separate set of columns for it's input and output definition.  I've put the theoretical "OneToManyField" in there to demonstrate what I'm trying to do.

```
class Registry(Model):
    input_dictionary = OneToManyField(ColumnDefinition)
    output_dictionary = OneToManyField(ColumnDefinition)
    created_date = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False)
```

A `ColumnDefinition` is only ever related to one Registry ever.  So it's not a Many to Many relationship.  If I put a `ForeignKey` on the `ColumnDefinition` instead to create a reverse relationship, it can only create a single reverse, whereas I need both an input and output reverse.

I don't want to have to do anything kludgey like adding a "column_registry_type" field onto `ColumnDefinition` if I can get around it.

Does anyone have any good ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What do you mean by "reverse"? Django automatically creates reverse relationships in its Model class (ORM) methods.

Comment: The problem is that I need *two* "reverse relationships" that are distinct.  If I put a ForeignKey on ColumnDefiniton to Registry, it only creates one.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to have two separate ColumnDefinition models, perhaps?

Comment: OK good clarification, thanks. Me thinks that with the two answers below you should arrive to a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add two `ForeignKeys` on `ColumnDefinition`, one for input and one for output, and give them separate `related_names`:

```
class ColumnDefinition(Model):
    ...
    input_registry = models.ForeignKey(Registry, related_name='input_columns')
    output_registry = models.ForeignKey(Registry, related_name='output_columns')
```

You can then access the set of columns like `registry.input_columns`.

Comment: I guess I could do that, but I would need to make sure that they were always mutually exclsuive.  A ColumnDefinition cannot ever be associated with two registries.

Comment: Well, the other way to do this would be to use a single `ForeignKey` and then have a separate column indicating its type (input or output). But you said you wanted to avoid that...

Comment: Hmm, looks like @Peter and I are giving you the same answers at the same time. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can and should define two different `ForeignKey` fields on `ColumnDefinition`.  Just make sure to specify a `related_name` value for at least one of them.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: This seems to add two kludgey fields where one will always be empty, or worse, if both of them are defined somehow it would cause a meltdown since they're not supposed to be "TwoToOne" related.

Comment: It's either that or define a single foreign key and use a different field to indicate the relationship type, maybe also adding some methods on `Registry` to help support your reverse lookups.  Did you have a database representation in mind?  That can help guide your model design in fringe cases like this.